# Exchanging an EU driving licence for a UK when the EU licence was obtained by exchanging from an "accession" country

Tags: united-kingdom, eu, eu-citizens, driving-license

I'm resident in the **UK** and have been for around 1 year, moved here from EU (**Belgium**) and currently driving in the UK with a UK registered car, insurance etc on the Belgium licence (declared as EU licence to the insurance company).

However I obtained the Belgium licence by exchanging an "**accession country**" (e.g. Bulgaria) licence at a time when the accession country was NOT YET a member of the EU (but is now)

Can I drive indefinitely on the Belgian/EU licence in the UK in this circumstance, or exchange it for a UK licence?
OR do I need to re-take the test in the UK since the original licence was issued "outside the EU" (at the time)?

Example text: (https://www.rbkc.gov.uk/parking-transport-and-streets/residents/eu-and-non-eu-licence-holders)

> **European Community/European Economic Area EC/EEA**
>
> A full, valid driving licence from an EC/EEA country allows you to drive in Great Britain (GB) until you are 70, or for three years after becoming a resident, whichever is the longer period.
>
> If your driving licence has been previously exchanged from a non-EC/EEA country you can drive for up to 12 months from the time you first became resident. After this time, you must exchange your licence for a British one.

Other, slightly different version: (https://www.askthe.police.uk/content/Q416.htm)

> Please note that someone can drive in Great Britain for only 12 months if they got their EU licence by exchanging a non-EU licence.

Comment: You could try [phoning the DVLA](https://www.gov.uk/contact-the-dvla/y/driving-licences-and-applications). Do report back if they give you an answer!